# How to prove $D^{\beta}D_{\alpha}w_{\beta}(\mathbf{x})=K(\mathbf{x})w_{\alpha}(\mathbf{x})$

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

I am reading a paper about fluid dynamics on the 2D manifold where I encounter an identity shown below. But I have no idea how to prove this? Can you help me?

For a solenoidal vector field $w_{\beta}(\mathbf{x})$ in the two-dimensional manifold, $w_{\beta}(\mathbf{x})$ satisfies:
$$D^{\beta}D_{\alpha}w_{\beta}(\mathbf{x})=K(\mathbf{x})w_{\alpha}(\mathbf{x}),$$
where $D_{\alpha}$ denotes covariant derivatives, $w_{\alpha}$ denotes vector's covariant, and $K(\mathbf{x})$ is local Gaussian curvature at the point $\mathbf{x}$ on the two-dimensional manifold.
I searched around in differential geometry books and cannot find this identity. Can someone help me?

Comment: Sure it's not a commutator on the left hand side, i.e. $[D^\beta,D_\alpha]w_\beta = K w_\alpha$ ?

Comment: Are you certain that *no* conditions are imposed on the vector field $w$? The equality is not true in general, though it is true if the divergence of $w$ vanishes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This equality is not true in general. As a counterexample, choose any vector field on $\mathbb{R}^2$ (with the Euclidean metric) which has nonconstant divergence. The right side will vanish since $K=0$, but the left side will not.

If, however, we require that $w$ be divergence-free, then the equlity *is* true (and gien the context of fluid dynamics, I suspect this to be the case). The result can be derived with a relatively short computation. One way is to start with the definition of the Riemann curvature tensor:
$$
D_\beta D_\alpha w^\delta-D_\alpha D_\beta w^\delta=R^\delta{}_{\gamma\beta\alpha}w^\gamma 
$$
Then, contract a pair of indices to obtain the desired $D_\beta D_\alpha w^\beta$ term:
$$
D_\beta D_\alpha w^\beta-D_\alpha D_\beta w^\beta=R^\beta{}_{\gamma\beta\alpha}w^\gamma
$$
The second term on the left vanishes since $\operatorname{div}(w)=D_\beta w^\beta=0$, and the right can be expressed in terms of $K$ by any expression which relates the Riemann/Ricci curvature to the Gauss curvature of a surface (e.g. $R_{\alpha\beta}=Kg_{\alpha\beta}$).